# What are the values of $x$ such that $\cos x \lessgtr \sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, solution-verification, circles

How can I find all values of $x \in [0, 2\pi]$ such that $\cos x > \sin x$ and, similarly, considering the same interval, the values which satisfy $\cos x < \sin x$?

My initial attempt was to divide both sides of the inequality by $\cos x$:
$$\tan x < 1$$

What should I do next? Is this path correct?

Comment: Hint: You can get this information from the unit circle directly.

Comment: You can divide both sides of an inequality  only if you know the divisor is positive. If the divisor is negative, you have to reverse the inequality.

Comment: Instead of dividing that causes inequalities to reverse when $\cos x$ changes sign, better use $\cos(x)-\sin(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\phi)$ and it is quite easy to study $\sin(x+\phi)$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Be careful with the division on both sides, as $\cos(x)$ changes sign in the interval you are considering. Actually, even $\sin(x)$ changes sign.

You could also try to solve the inequality with a graphical method, plotting the two functions $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ on a paper and seeing where one of them is greater than the other.